# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-2

i am using **spring 3.1.0.RELEASE**, and my servlet container is **tomcat 7** and my IDE is **eclipse indigo**
and the jar **spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar** which contains the **DispatcherServlet**
exists in the lib folder, and yet when running the application, i am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

please advise why i am getting this exception, and how to fix it.

EDIT: following are my configuration files:

**1- .springBeans:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beansProjectDescription>
    <version>1</version>
    <pluginVersion><![CDATA[2.9.0.201203011806-RELEASE]]></pluginVersion>
    <configSuffixes>
        <configSuffix><![CDATA[xml]]></configSuffix>
    </configSuffixes>
    <enableImports><![CDATA[false]]></enableImports>
    <configs>
        <config>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/checkout-servlet.xml</config>
    </configs>
    <configSets>
    </configSets>
</beansProjectDescription>
```

**2- web.xml:**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Checkout</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>checkout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>checkout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**3- checkout-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>

    <bean id="myService" class="com.myapp.MyService"/>

</beans>
```

also when trying to access any page in the application, i get the exception:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet checkout is not available

type Status report

message Servlet checkout is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet checkout is not available) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
```

Comment: can you post your spring config files and tell us what app-server is it supposed to run on?

Comment: @Gergely Szilagyi, i updated the question.

Comment: deleted my answer, because it wasn't useful. sorry :(

Comment: @iNan, i am using eclipse indigo

Comment: I believe it is not directly a CNF on DispatcherServlet but a dependent class has thrown an error. Check if you see any other nested exception.

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml?

Comment: When you say spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar is in the lib folder. Is that WEB-INF/lib or <TOMCAT HOME>/lib?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found that in the **deployment assembly**, there was the entry:

```
[persisted container] org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2_classpath_container
```

i removed it, and added the `maven dependencies` entry, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 258):

You need to add the "Maven Dependency" in the Deployment Assembly

- right click on your project and choose properties.
- click  on Deployment Assembly.
- click add
- click on "Java Build Path Entries"
- select Maven Dependencies"
- click Finish.

Rebuild and deploy again

Note: This is also applicable for *non maven* project.

Comment: Nice - I was confused to see even after adding the proper dependency in my pom.xml didn't solved the error until I followed as above..

Comment: Nice.. perfect solution

Comment: Why does this work? I mean, shouldn't all maven dependencies be available? If I was using the Tomcat7 pluging with tomcat7:run, how would this be accomplished?

Comment: Works like charm!

Comment: This is also applicable for non maven project.!!

I created a maven project and i got same problem. this solution worked for me.

Comment: Before i add ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, the application worked properly. After i add that view resolver, i got this issue. Can somebody explain me the reason for getting this issue??

Comment: this worked for me, but one thing i was not able to understand this problem occurred to me when i have change the project java version to 1.8

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Eclipse IDE, I tried  all these steps, but not able to resolve the issue. Please help! I am using Spring 6.0.0 with Tomcat 9.

Comment: This works, but the problem keeps coming back. It will work one time, then it breaks again and I have to add the Maven Dependencies again to fix it, which it does. Then later I find they're missing yet again, without any change to the files in my project folder according to git (and I'm including eclipse dot files there as well to track them). Would be nice to know why that setting keeps dropping the Maven Dependencies apparently without any apparent action on my part (using Eclipse Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0) on Debian 12).

Answer (score 40):

Two possible answers:

1- You did not include spring-beans and spring-context jars in your lib.
If you are using maven  (which will help a lot) those two lines will be enough

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

2- The necessary jars are in your classpath but are not deployed on tomcat.

Comment: Nice that you solved the problem, but I do not think that it can be understood from your problem that you are using maven.

Comment: maven is tagged in the question !

Comment: adding `spring-webmvc` to my `pom.xml` will solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can somebody please tell why we need spring-context dependency?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with Idea Intellij and Spring 4. I fixed the problem and I wanted to share the answer with you.

I use tomcat 7 / idea intellij 13 / spring 4.

pom.xml dependencies:

```xml
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
enter code here
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

In idea Intellij, you need to go to File -> Project Settings -> Artifacts.

Then
[image]

clean -> rebuild the project -> build the artifact, and everything will be ok.

Comment: You're a genius. Could you explain what difference it makes? How come Maven imports everything, but you still need to do that so it works?

Comment: @DMurta who said that maven exports everything?

Answer (score 13):

This solves the problem for me. It's easy and pretty simply explained.

Step 1

- Right click on project
- Click on Properties

Step 2

- Click on Deployment Assembly Tab in the
- Click Add...

Step 3

- Click on Java Build Path Entries

Step 4

- Click on Maven Dependencies
- Click Finish button

Step 5

- Redeploy Spring MVC application to Tomcat again
- Restart Tomcat
- List item

[classnotfoundexception](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-exception-spring-mvc-tomcat-and-404-error/)

Comment: Would you reconsider the grade you gave to my proposition?

Answer (score 7):

If all of these advice doesn't work, you should re-create your Server (Tomcat or like that). That solved my problem.

Comment: any Idea how this is possible ? In my case I had to restart application (considering it was embedded tc9 , it also recreated it..)

Answer (score 6):

Include below dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>{spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same Issue. When I saw into maven repository .m2 folder(....m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc) in my local I found two 3.2.0.RELEASE folders. SO I removed one.
Then I went to project, right click->properties->deployment essembly-> add maven dependencies.
clean build and then restart the server. 
Then the DispatcherServlet got loaded.

Comment: Yes, this resolved my issue too, any idea why it is required to add dependencies in deployment assembly in eclipse ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to **properties** of **Project** which your working
2. Choose the **Deployment Assembly** menu and Click on **add button**
3. opt the **Java Build Path Entries** and Click on **Maven Dependencies**
4. **Build** the project and run

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Maven Dependencies option when i click on Java Build Path Entries.

Comment: i did not know in which aspect your asking this question. Please try to post new question.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I get this trouble after using the maven's update project utility.
I tried all the workarounds you suggested but nothing seemed to work. 
At the end the solution was simply to remove the project from the server to ensure that it was clean, and add it again. Then it works, I hope this solution could help any of you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GlassFish server and the error will be resolved. I tried with tomcat7 and tomcat8 but this error was coming continuously but resolved with GlassFish. I think it's a problem with server.

These are the results with tomcat7:
[image: Results with tomcat7]

Here are the results with GlassFish:
[image: Results with GlassFish]

Answer (score 1):

right click on your project and choose properties.
click on Deployement Assembly.
click add
click on "Java Build Path Entries"
select Maven Dependencies"
click Finish.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful for someone, so I'll post it here.
I was missing this dependency on my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by following these steps:

- Right click in the project > Configure > Convert to Maven project
- After the conversion, right click in the project > Maven > Update project

This fixes the "Deployment Assembly" settings of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Move the jar files from your classpath to **web-inf/lib**, and run a new tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, 
Simply add your jars inside WEB-INF-->lib folder..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in WebSphere, but couldn't find a solution even though I verified the Spring dependencies were there and it ran in tomcat just fine. I ended up uninstalling the application and was still getting the error so I think WebSphere was hanging onto some corrupt instance.

To fix the issue I had to reinstall the application, stop it, uninstall it and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a mistake in the `pom.xml` - I'd set `<scope>provided<scope>` on my dependencies, and this was making them not get copied during the `mvn package` stage.

My symptoms were the error message the OP posted, and that the jars were not included in the WEB-INF/lib path inside the .war after package was run.  When I removed the scope, the jars appeared in the output, and all loads up fine now.