# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in spring project

Tags: java

one hello.jsp

web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for 
    handling all application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"

```
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p">

<bean id="viewResolver"

    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">

        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>

    </property>

    <property name="suffix">

        <value>.jsp</value>

    </property>

</bean>
<bean name="/hello.html" class="com.spring.HelloWorldController"></bean>
</beans>
```

JAR Files are:
spring.jar
spring-webmvc.jar
spring-aop
spring-beans
spring-context
spring-context-support
spring-core
spring-jdbc
spring-orm
spring-source
spring-test
spring-tx

Comment: Did u added the spring-framework library and spring mvc library?

Comment: @TI: It is pretty clear that the exception is caused because of the nonexistent `org.springframework.web`

Comment: @Rahul yes all library are added

Comment: @SagarVaghela: I have added an answer 8 minutes ago, please take a look.

Comment: @RaulRene ok but i have already added all jar so?

Comment: @SagarVaghela - Which Spring JARs are in the deployed WEB-INF/lib directory?  List them in the Question please.

Comment: @StephenC I have display all spring jar in question

Comment: Plese [click][1] to check solution that worked for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27582085/1591934

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException` clearly indicates that you are missing `org.springframework.web.servlet` classes.

If you are not using *Maven*, make sure you include all the appropriate *Spring* JARs.

If you are using *Maven*, make sure you include the `spring-web` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version><!-- Your spring version here --></version>
    </dependency>
```

If none of these work, [take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used Ivy and I faced the same issue. You can do either of the two

1. Either move your libraries to **WEB-INF/lib** . Because this is the
   folder from where Eclipse searches for corresponding jars. OR
2. Let Eclipse know that it can search the jars from ivy library folder
   which is not same as **WEB-INF/lib** i.e Change java build path in Deployment Assembly via Project properties.

For 2nd approach you can refer [details post with screenshots](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/05/javalangclassnotfoundexception.html) (Link to my personal blog with more detials). Or you can also go through similar question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765821/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv).

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in spring project

The issue is necessary jar are not present in the proper classpath

Solution

Place all the necessary jars in the classpath .Since the project is dynamic webproject place all the spring jars in the WEB-INF/Lib folder

The issue will be resloved

Comment: All necessary jar files are already added in project WEB-INF/Lib folder and also added in classpath..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it this way. If all the required libraries are added and you are still getting this error. Try running this in command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

then

```
mvn clean install
```

If this doesn't resolve it, rightclick on your eclipse project,
go to >>properties >> targeted runtime
then click the checkbox next to

> apache tomcat v8.0

depending on the version of you tomcat.
If you are running jboss, choose a jboss version instead.
and then after this run the above 2 commands(mvn eclipse:eclipse and mvn clean install) again.

Answer (score -1):

Problem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in spring project.

By adding the below jars into WEB-INF/Lib folder we can resolve this issue.

```
org.springframework.asm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Of Course you will be added in Build Path but it will take up to Compile time only. So we have to added above jars into WEB-INF/Lib folder