# Servlet /webapp threw load() exception

Tags: java, linux, spring-mvc, tomcat

When I start tomcat server in linux, war file should auto-deploy the webapp. When I see localhost.log file, found the following error

```
    SEVERE: Servlet /webapp threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

No idea whats going on and how its happening, cause when I do the same in my local box, I dont see any errors! My assumption is,using java 7 to build in local and using Java 8 in linux.

Is that whats happening or I am missing something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what is the Spring version? I think there is some issue with Spring 3 and Java 8.

If you are using Spring 3 change it to Spring 4 build and deploy using Java 8

or

Downgrade Java to 7 and use spring 3!

Comment: perfect, it worked. was using spring 3. modified dependencies to spring 4.0.6!

Comment: I am using spring 4 and java 8 ...still getting this issue

Answer (score 22):

This issue occured to me because i didn't provide path in Deployement option in properties of project:

Right click on project ---> select "properties" --> Deployement assembly --> "ADD" option -->
select "java build path entries" --> select path

Comment: yeah  this  is  an perfect answer for me tnx!

Comment: I am not able to see anything in java build path it shows me empty box with back button (finish disabled)

Comment: No Deployment assembly option in properties

Answer (score 1):

this is the prefect solution , i had been struggling since two days for the same.

Right click on project ---> select "properties" --> Deployement assembly --> "ADD" option --> select "java build path entries" --> select path(maven dependencies)-->Finish