# Very simple Spring MVC configuration error. What is wrong int my web.xml and dependent servlet config file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

My web app works ok, but I get following error while loading it in Tomcat 8 from eclipse 4.4. So what is wrong? Is something wrong with my config or anything with tomcat?

```
Nov 16, 2014 11:59:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /zhelloweb threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
```

Here is web.xml:-

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>  
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

here is app context.xml:-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is pom.xml file :-

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-   
 4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>zhelloweb</groupId>
 <artifactId>zhelloweb</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

   <properties>
     <java-version>1.7</java-version>
     <org.springframework-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
     <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
     <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
   <!-- Form Validation using Annotations --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
         <exclusions>
             <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
     </dependency>

      <!-- AspectJ -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
         <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
     </dependency>

      <!-- Logging -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- @Inject -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- Test -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>

    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>

    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
 </project>
```

Comment: Do you have spring-web*.jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: No, It is maven project, it has pom.xml

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the following dependencies in your class path. If you are using maven like tool of dependencies managment you have to add this:

```
 <dependencies>
    ....

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>yourSPringVersion</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>yourSPringVersion</version>
  </dependency>

  ....

</dependencies>
```

For some others information about these modules you can read some information [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-web)

Comment: I have these in my pom.xml. I added pom.xml in my question.

Comment: Check if you have the jars listed above in your war. And then clean the project and reinstall it.