# Error deploying Spring project to Weblogic

Tags: eclipse, spring, weblogic

We're migrating our development environment to a new server, and I've been having trouble getting my webapp to deploy from the new development environment.

The webserver it is deploying to is exactly same server.

My process for deploying is, I check out the project as a maven project from SVN, and right click -> run as -> run on server.

It works on the old environment, but not the new environment.

The question is, looking at this stack trace, what is going on?

Going down top from bottom:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:188)
```

This exception receieved at the eclipse plugin in.

```
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'AnalystNoteBookSupportTool.war'
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
```

This exception thrown by the web logic server.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
```

This exception thrown by the weblogic server.... when it can't find the class in the .war file sent to it?

Full Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:188)
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:509)
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1504)
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:921)
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:709)
          at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:556)
          at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
          at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3154)
          at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
          at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'MyWebApp.war'
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
          at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
          at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
          at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
          at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
          at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
          at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
          at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
          at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
          at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
          at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
          at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
          at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
          at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
          at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
          at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
          at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
          at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
          at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

          at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
          at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
          at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
          at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
          at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processServlets(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:225)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:209)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:105)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1368)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:449)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:493)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
```

Comment: How is spring packaged into the .ear file? Can you install the .ear without using eclipse?

Comment: Answer solved here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv