# CNF org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have included `org.springframework.spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE` and tried with `3.2.4.RELEASE` even though i am getting this error.

**POM**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**error**

```
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVCTutorial threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Any one help

**EDIT**
I have added Maven Dependency in Deployment assembly, I'm getting this error now

**ERROR**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringMVC-servlet.xml]
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW8RW.png)

Comment: Try adding the javax.servlet dependency to your pom.

Comment: i have added <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>.
same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDE is eclipse, Try the following. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv)

You need to add the "Maven Dependency" in the Deployment Assembly

**1. right click on your project and choose properties.**
2. click on Deployment Assembly.
**3. click add**
4. click on "Java Build Path Entries"
**5. select Maven Dependencies"**
6. click Finish.
**7. Rebuild and deploy again**

Comment: I dont have "src" inside "Java Resource" is that a problem. any solution to fix this.  Class files are not created and "WEB_INF/lib" is empty

Comment: please have a look at the project structure

Comment: it looks bad. Find another tutorial. This one will give you headaches.

Comment: Any suggestions for working, basic SpringMVC project

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/spring-mvc-helloworld-using-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: I'm trying to call .js and .css from my index.jsp file. I'm getting this error `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWorld/test.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`. can you help me with this

Comment: open a new question . Dont forget to show your dispatcherservlet and the structure tree of your webapp.