# Spring MVC ClassNotFoundException even the deployment assembly has Maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, classcastexception

Geeting the bellow error while starting the server with the spring application

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
```

Checked the deployment assembly. Maven Dependencies was already there

[image]
Spring mvc jar already configured in the pom.xml. Also checked in the folder the spring mvc jar was there.Please refer the attahement. Using the tomcat 8.0 server

[image]

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SupportHelper</groupId>
  <artifactId>SupportHelper</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>SupportHelper</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>supportHelper</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>supportHelper</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

...

Comment: Clear maven cache

Answer (score 0):

1. update project by right click on project -> Maven -> update project and then build project and run as maven clean install

Comment: Tried that. While Updating in the console found FileNotFoundException for common logging. Had been added the common-logging also in the POM.xml. Still there is no change.

Answer (score -1):

Can u check if the below dependency is included in your pom.xml/build.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version><!-- Your spring version here --></version>
    </dependency>
```

Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv), might be useful..

--edited--

Spring Jars are not being resolved at runtime by your server. Please check your WEB-INF/lib to see if the jars are available.

Comment: You can clearly see it in their maven dependencies in the picture.

Comment: It is there buddy.

Comment: @DIM I already checked that link,. As it was not worked out for me raised this question. Anyhow thanks for your support.