# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet : Spring MVC and Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-migration

I am creating a web application using **Spring MVC and Eclipse IDE**.
**Spring Version- 6.0.3**
To configure the project, I followed the following steps-

1. Added dependencies in **pom.xml-**

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

2. Added Tomcat Server Runtime to the build path-
   [image]
3. Added **maven dependencies to deployment assembly-**
   [image]
4. **web.xml-** (in WEB-INF folder)

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Spring MVC Demo</display-name>

    <!-- Configure dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- / means handle all the requests from all urls -->
</web-app>
```

5. **dispatcherservlet-servlet.xml** (in WEB-INF folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"

    xmlns:p="http://springframework.org/schema/p">
<!-- Enable annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="spring-mvc-demo.src.main.java.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <!-- View Resolver bean -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        name="viewResolver">
        <!-- Inject two properties -->
        <!-- Location for pages is given to prefix -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <!-- ending of page is .jsp -->
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <!-- Example name /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp (here the name hello will be 
            given by controller) -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

6. Placed index.jsp under **views folder** in WEB-INF-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is home page</h1>
        <h1>Called by home controller</h1>
        <h1>fired for /</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

7. Created HomeController.java class in src/main/java/controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String home() {
        //return the name of the page
        System.out.println("Hello this is home URL");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I have created a controller with the url **/home/current**. On visiting this url I expect to see the desired **index.jsp**.
**Problem-**
When I **"Run on Server"** I get following error-

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcherservlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
```

Please help me to find the error in my configuration and the reason I get this error.
I saw several other posts, re-checked my steps but still getting the same error-
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the first screenshot in your question, you're using Tomcat 9. But for Spring 6 you need a minimum of Tomcat 10. Tomcat 10 is the first to use `jakarta.*` namespace whereas older versions used `javax.*` namespace.

Spring 6 (and Spring Boot 3) is the first version to use `jakarta.*` namespace whereas older versions used `javax.*` namespace.

So you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade Tomcat to a minimum of 10.
2. Or, downgrade Spring to a maximum of 5.

Clearly, option 1 is the recommended way to go in long term.

By the way, Spring 6 requires Java 17 not Java 1.7 as seen in the first screenshot in your question.

#### See also:

- [A Java 17 and Jakarta EE 9 baseline for Spring Framework 6](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6)
- [Apache Tomcat Versions](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/how-to-properly-configure-jakarta-ee-libraries-in-maven-pom-xml-for-tomcat/65704617#65704617)

Comment: I changed my tomcat version to 10.0. Now, I am getting a different error- Jan 22, 2023 11:24:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-mvc-demo/
Jan 22, 2023 11:24:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-mvc-demo/home/current

Comment: Yup. That's a different problem. Continue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41577234 or ask a new question.

Comment: Thank You. I resolved it, had a problem with component scanning.

Comment: Although my project is working, but I am still getting a error in the WEB-INF/views/index.jsp (highlighted in red as an error)- Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet", determined from the Dynamic Web Module facet 
  version (3.1), was not found on the Java Build Path
 - The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet", determined from the Dynamic Web Module facet 
  version (3.1), was not found on the Java Build Path

Comment: That is a false negative. Technically speaking, Eclipse needs to be updated to the version which recognizes and supports `jakarta.*`. This is unrelated to the problem asked in the current question.

Comment: You need to add the namespace/schema location to web-app tag in your deployment descriptor (ie., web.xml) to get rid errors in your JSP files, also update the Dynamic Web Module facet version to v5.0. Refer to this link for more detailed answer https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1112198/

Answer (score 1):

While working with spring 6.0 and jakartgha servelet api(6.0.0) and jsp api (3.1.1) we have use tomcat 10.1 or 10.0 at least