# Spring Boot 3 throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletContext

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-migration

In my gradle project, I am trying to bring up the application locally and getting below error :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletContext

Versions used :
Java 17
Springboot 3.1.3
Jakarta servlet 6.0.0

I looked up the compatible versions table, jakarta servlet above 4.x is compatible with spring 3.x
Other version checks also done, but still the issue persists

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any `jakarte.servlet` dependency, that is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. Please show your `pom.xml`

Comment: Agreed with M. Deinum : could you please share your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet : Spring MVC and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198688/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-jakarta-servlet-http-httpservlet-spring-mvc)